# Firefox 31.7 to 40 is not showing flash inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, flash, swfobject

I have an iframe, which points to a externally hosted .swf. It works fine in Chrome, but not in firefox. How can I get it to work in firefox?

```
<iframe id="iTest" src="http://speedtest-wellington.spark.co.nz/netgauge.swf" width="635" scrolling="no" height="445" frameborder="0" align="middle" style="margin:0;padding:0border:0 none;width:635px;height:445px;overflow:none;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Your browser does not support iframes.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</iframe>
```

Here is the problematic page located here [here](http://www.spark.co.nz/myspark/myinternet/testyourspeed/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was that a containing parent element had:

```
moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 -transform: translate(0px, 0px);
```

this bug is documented `https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644832`